# Unable to receive custom Ethernet frame

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I created a socket_raw, the custom protocol type is 0x2328, and I send 0x2328 type data on another machine. The capture packet can be captured, but recvfrom cannot receive it. What should I do? Here is the code received.

```
struct sockaddr_ll sll;
struct ifreq ifr;

if ((sd = socket (PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons (0x2328))) < 0) {
    perror ("socket() failed to get socket descriptor for using ioctl() ");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Use ioctl() to look up interface name and get its MAC address.
memset (&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
sprintf (ifr.ifr_name, "eth1");

if (ioctl (sd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0) {
    perror ("ioctl() failed");
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset (&sll, 0, sizeof (sll));
int sll_len;
sll.sll_family  = AF_PACKET;
sll.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
sll_len         = sizeof(sll);

char buffer[1024];
recvfrom(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, &sll_len);
```

Comment: does `recvfrom` block or return `-1`?  If the latter, what is the resulting `errno`?

Comment: I also wonder if `recvfrom` is unhappy that you're passing a `sockaddr_ll` struct rather than a `sockaddr`.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b  `recvfrom` is block . `sockaddr` has been used and cannot receive data

Comment: I found the reason. Previously, because send and recv were sent and received on the same network card, it could not be received.

Comment: Hmm.  Is there any frame-level analogue of the IP-loopback interface?